# PowerBI DAX - Using a measure as a filter within a CALCULATE function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a DAX measure in PowerBI that will provide an aggregate of sales on a specific date. 
I need that date to be controlled by a date slicer. Specifically the the maximum date on the slicer.

I would expect this to be a `Calculate()` function. So something like the following if it was hard coded with a date.

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(FactInternetSales2[Sales]), DimDate2[Dim Date] = DATE(2018, 06, 18))
```

But I need the filter component of the the `Calculate()` function *(i.e , DimDate2[Dim Date] = DATE(2018,06,18))*  to be dynamically populated from the max date on the date slicer. I understand, however that a measure can't be used as a filter in a calculate function - so I can't create a measure such as follows to identify the maximum date

```
=LASTDATE(DimDate2[Dim Date])
```

and then use it in the `Calculate()` function such as

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(FactInternetSales2[Sales]), DimDate2[Dim Date] = LASTDATE(DimDate2[Dim Date])
```

Can anyone outline how I can use the maximum date from the slicer to filter the `Calculate()` function, or achieve the same outcome?

A copy of my working file is located here 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d1JiyPm1jOD9XkVqv3Q5pm0vk1FMotH9/view?usp=sharing

Cheers
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in the parameter value into a variable.

```
SalesSum =
VAR EndDate = LASTDATE ( DimDate2[Dim Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( FactInternetSales2[Sales] ), DimDate2[Dim Date] = EndDate )
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis - Just what I was after!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Calculate()` function with a filter like this:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[SalesValue]), FILTER(Table1, Table1[Year] = 2019))
```

To get the value from a slicer you go to `Modeling > New Parameter`. Here you can specifie your parameter needs and hit `OK`. Now you gat a new table and column for this parameter on the fields pane. Just reference now on this column with the following code:

```
=SELECTEDVALUE(ParameterTable[ParameterValue])
```